# how to impute more than one specific columns in DataSet: Python(sklearn)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn

with no time waste, heading towards the Problem.
I am actually imputing my DataSet with **sklearn.SimpleImputer** in **Python**.
But my DataSet contains some columns with integers and some columns with other alphabets points. So, I am using **Median** to fill empty spaces and I just want to do it for only my specific columns with integers, not with the whole DataSet.
I tried this:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy="median")
imputer.fit(students['age'], ['sex'], ['failures'])
```

I want to do imputation with only these columns which only have intigers values not all dataset because all dataset contains columns with alphbets datapoints too whose **Median** can not be taken.

From the above code, I got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2894             try:
-> 2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: ('age', 'sex', 'failures')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-8961e0ce249f> in <module>
      2 from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
      3 imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy="median")
----> 4 imputer.fit(students['age', 'sex', 'failures'])

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2900             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2901                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2902             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2903             if is_integer(indexer):
   2904                 indexer = [indexer]

 ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:
 -> 2897                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2898 
   2899         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: ('age', 'sex', 'failures')
```

The link to ***Data*** is https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00320/

**THANKS! HOPE YOU UNDERSTOOD THE PROBLEM, I TRIED MY BEST TO EXPLAIN IT.**

Comment: You need to pass `numpy.ndarray` not `pandas series or column`

Comment: hi ashraful16, please describe a little more.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
imputer.fit_transform([students['age'], students['sex'], students['failures']])
```